# Which one is more grammatical and idiomatic, "view something is" or "view something as"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4qfdCwys2ew?t=39)

> Something hits you really hard and then goes away, and then
>   nothing happens for a very long period of time.
>   And you'll learn this in the future, you can kind of view
>   this is an impulse.

Is it more grammatical to rewrite the last part "you can kind of view
this **is** an impulse" as "you can kind of view this **as** an impulse"?

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to say here? "Something hits you really hard and then goes away, and then nothing happens for a very long period of time. And you'll learn this in the future, you can kind of view this is an impulse." I am unsure of the context.

'View this is' is not grammatically correct, as far as I know. Perhaps you could say 'see this is', if this is what you are trying to say.

If you are trying to say 'this can be seen as an impulse', you should use 'view this as'.

Answer (score 1):

"View this as" is a phrase meaning to look at something from another perspective, usually as a way to recharacterize an action or an argument.

For example:

> The child complained of a stomach ache.  I view this as a way to stay home from school.
>
> I didn't want to go out with my coworkers for lunch because I brought my own lunch.  My coworkers view this as me not wanting to spend time with outside the office.